# Select New Date from One Table into Another Table with Group By

Tags: mysql, datetime, aggregate-functions

I have 2 Tables:

orders

- purchase_date (this is type 'datetime')
- item_price
- sku
- misc other data

total_sales_by_date

- date
- total_sales

The orders table is getting updated on a daily basis by an API. The total_sales_by_date table is only adding up ALL the sales across every sku, and grouping them by date with a SUM total for all skus/sales on that date. I'm using this query:

```
INSERT INTO total_sales_by_date SELECT DATE(purchase_date) AS date, SUM(item_price) AS total_sales FROM orders GROUP BY date
```

For database efficiency, I want to update the 2nd table on a daily basis with only the NEW sales data that came into the 1st table by API. ie- I don't want to re-insert the old data I have already in the 2nd table.

Further, I'd like to create a procedure where this runs every day at 4am (or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query like this. you can run how often you want. It insert only orders to yesterday and checks also the max date from total_sales_by_date

```
INSERT INTO total_sales_by_date (date,total_sales)
SELECT
    DATE(purchase_date) AS date,
    SUM(item_price) AS total_sales
  FROM orders
  where ( 
    SELECT IF( max(date) is null,'1900-01-01',max(date) + interval 1 day)
    FROM total_sales_by_date
    ) < purchase_date
  AND purchase_date < date(now() - interval 1 day)
  GROUP BY date;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run the following query sometime after midnight local time each day you'll get what you want.  I suggest running it after 3am so you don't get anomalies on the days when daylight savings time starts or ends.

```
INSERT INTO total_sales_by_date 
SELECT DATE(purchase_date) AS date, 
       SUM(item_price) AS total_sales
  FROM orders
 WHERE purchase_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
   AND purchase_date < CURDATE()
 GROUP BY DATE(purchase_date)
```

This selects yesterday's sales, summarizes them, and inserts them into your `total_sales` table.  You can run this using a MySQL `event`. Here's an [explanation of the event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html).

**But** it's possible you're doing something the hard way, where you could make it easier.  Your `total_sales` table is sometimes called a "materialized view." That is, it's derived entirely from some other table and contains no additional information.  You could do away entirely with this business of updating it regularly by just defining it as an ordinary view.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW total_sales
    AS
    SELECT DATE(purchase_date) AS date, 
           SUM(item_price) AS total_sales
      FROM orders
     GROUP BY DATE(purchase_date)
```

Then, whenever you need rows from `total_sales` MySQL will fetch them from `orders`. If you define a compound index on `(purchase_date, item_price)` on your `orders` table, using the view should not be too much of a performance hit.

Comment: whoa. This is very interesting. So the end game is to chart this stuff- either in Excel, or in a web based platform. With that in mind, will using views THEN create more resources on the server than simply downloading the previously filled tables?

Comment: I guess you mean *consume* more resources. (I wish queries could *create* more resources. :-) :-)   Not significantly, unless you run this charting program many times an hour, and you have at least 100,000 rows in your `orders` table. At any rate, the usual practice is to use simple SQL tools (queries, views, etc) to get your work done. If you find  you have performance problems, then you add indexes. If that doesn't work, you use the big hammer -- materialized view -- that you've shown here.

Comment: Your strategy here has been to use your time (the only irreplaceable resource you have) to overcome what you believe will be a MySQL server bottleneck.  No sense using any more time until you're sure the bottleneck is real. It probably isn't.